# The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly This environment variable is needed to run this program"

Tags: java, tomcat7

I have installed JDK 7 and tomcat 7 and set the following environment variables:

```
PATH: ......C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_51;F:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\bin;
CATALINA_HOME: F:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.52;
JAVA_HOME: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_51;
JRE_HOME: C:\Progra~1\Java\jre7;
```

When I try to run the command `catalina.bat`, it throws the following error:

```
The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly 
This environment variable is needed to run this program.
```

when executing the command `setclasspath.bat`, it's throwing the following error:

```
The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program.
```

and when I try to execute the command `service.bat`, the error is:

```
The tomcat7.exe was not found...
The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.
This environment variable is needed to run this program".
```

And also when I try to execute `%CATALINA_HOME%` from `RUN`, the error message says:

```
Windows cannot find the path.
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Where do you set the environment variables? And, what user are you using to run the batch files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra semicolon at the end of the CATALINA_HOME variable (and others). Try with:

```
F:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.52
```

instead of

```
F:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.52;
```

Comment: @ David Removing ; at the end of the variables worked for me. Thanks many!! :)

Answer (score 1):

[Setting the JAVA_HOME , CATALINA_HOME Environment Variable on Windows](https://struts2spring.wordpress.com/2009/09/22/setting-the-java_home-catalina_home-environment-variable-on-windows/)

The simplest way to do this in most Windows cases is to set environment variables:

On Win 7:

Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced (tab) -> Environment Variables (button)

Comment: @David Levesque may have the correct answer, I never realized that semicolon is significant in NTFS pathnames.

Comment: I've been told that just providing a link as an anwser without any further explanations was not a best practice here...The link could be dead one day so we will have no more trace about what it was talking about

Comment: Fair point.  Will correct.

Comment: @ David Removing ; at the end of the variables worked for me. Thanks many!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Every instance of CMD started by a user, *including* the implicit instance automatically started when you run a batch file via Start>Run, inherits the environment settings of the current user.

You must set the environment variables for the user, instead of via a Command Prompt, because if you set environment variables via the Command Prompt, the environment will be effective *only* for *that* particular instance of the Command Prompt.

I forgot exactly where (I don't have my laptop with me at the moment), but it's somewhere within the "Advanced Settings" dialog box (reachable via Win+Break).

Answer (score 0):

on win7 start window type env it will directly open environment variable window set this paths-

`JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8` (add path where your java is installed)
`JRE_HOME=`add path where your jre is installed
`Catalina_home=`add path where your tomcat is installed

in path variable just add
`%CATALINA_HOME%\lib`